# Pros and cons of R squared and normalized RMSE as a scale-free out-of-sample performance metric for regression?

Tags: model-evaluation, out-of-sample

I am mainly considering the nRMSE = RMSE/sd, but if you are more familiar with RMSE/mean or RMSE/min-max that would also be interesting. I am looking for pros/cons for the two, or different use cases where each one is best suited. Thanks in advance for any input!

Edit: More information provided in comments:

For use cases I am thinking that for example r squared is more known in litterature, so a pro might be interpretability for a wider audience. For nRMSE: for example it could be that it is more accurate in identifying the best model? I'm not sure myself. I struggled to find more than a definition and a formula on nRMSE, so it was difficult to find pros/cons. For use cases I'm thinking a ML regression model with 20 variables and 5000 rows.

Comment: Can you offer any more specifics about the use-case you're interested in? This is a fairly open-ended question, which is [generally discouraged](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here, so anything you can do to make the question more specific and targeted may help you to get a better answer. Similarly, what work have you already done to answer this? Any preliminary thoughts on the pros/cons? Any answers you've come across in your earlier research, and any opinions on those answers?

Comment: For use cases I am thinking that for example r squared is more known in litterature, so a pro might be interpretability for a wider audience. For nRMSE: for example it could be that it is more accurate in identifying the best model? I'm not sure myself. I struggled to find more than a definition and a formula on nRMSE, so it was difficult to find pros/cons. For use cases I'm thinking a ML regression model with 20 variables and 5000 rows if that helps

Comment: @dlid I added the information you were looking for. Are you now able to find any pros/cons for this scenario?